# Looping and append to dataframe with column names in Pyhton

Tags: dataframe, loops, append

I had this challenge of looping through and appending to a data frame in 2 separate columns. I would like the result of col1 and col2 to be appended to the data frame under the columns 'col1' & 'col2'.

What i have so far is the below:

```
result = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['col1', 'col2'])
for i in range(5):
    col1 = i + 1
    col2 = i + 100
    result.append(pd.concat([str(col1), col2]))
```

Which outputs:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

My desired output is:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 |
| 2 | 102 |
| 3 | 103 |
| 4 | 104 |
| 5 | 105 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using `append` here is necessary, you may do

```
result = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['col1', 'col2'])
for i in range(5):
    col1 = i + 1
    col2 = i + 100
    result = result.append({'col1': str(col1), 'col2': col2}, ignore_index=True)
```

Otherwise, with `concat`

```
result = pd.concat([
    pd.Series({'col1': str(i + 1), 'col2': i + 100})
        for i in range(5)
], axis=1).transpose()
```

Or I would do this

```
result = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': list(map(str, range(1, 6))),
    'col2': list(range(100, 105)),
})
```

Comment: Hi Raymond! Thank you very much for the reply (and the options). Actually in the context of my task, append is what I need, so thank you. But, when I copy the top section (with append), result seems to leave an empty data frame with just the column names; is there something I am missing?

Comment: Oh! I just fixed that.

Comment: thank you! didn't realise you didn't need 'result =' .. thank you!  ps, you thought my question was framed ok and useful, I am trying to get some more privileges and a vote would help :)